# Randomizing 3 arrays in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I would like to randomize three arrays for fonts, font size, font weight.
I then need to display the results of the three arrays in a div, with a class name of randomFont.
So each time I use the class randomFont, it will return a random font/size/weight.

Any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

Let's say I have 3 variables in each array.

- array 1 (fonts) > font 1, font 2, font 3
- array 2 (font weight) > bold, light, 100
- array 3 (font-size) > 12px, 24px, 100px

Then I want an an array to randomly choose one from each and display the output in a div>class called randomFont.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see one approach at http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/bwsvy/

```
var fonts = ['Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Georgia', 'Tahoma', 'Verdana'];
var weights = ['normal', 'bold', 'lighter'];
var sizes = ['16px', '20px', '24px', '36px', '40px'];

var choose = function(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
};

// ...
var text = choose(sizes) + ' ' + choose(weights) + ' '  +  choose(fonts);
output.innerHTML = '<div class="randomFont">' + text + '</div>';
// e.g. '24px bold Tahoma'
```

Comment: question: is it possible to have the  three variable pointing to classes?
e.g var fonts = ['.font1', '.font2', '.font3', '.font4', '.font5'];
  also is it possible to have this function auto run on page load, and just look for a div tag called "output"? as opposed to creating one? really hope you can help.

Comment: Yes, it would be quite possible.  Have you tried either of them?  Have you searched the web for the page load question?

Comment: i tried the var classes like above but tart isnt working, searching for it, im finding nothing :(

Answer (score 2):

Don't really need jQuery but this should do it, since you didn't supply any example code I've had to make it up but this should get you on your way.

`var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];`

do this for each array.

Comment: I think you get a random element, but not a randomized array?

Comment: lets say i have 3 variables in each array.

array 1 (fonts) > font 1, font 2, font 2  
array 2 (font weight) > bold, light, 100 
array 3 (font-size)> 12px, 24px, 100px

then i want an an array to randomly choose one from each and display the output in a div>class called randomFont.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by randomizing the arrays.  If you have a fixed list of values and you want to rearrange them in place, then you want a shuffle functions, something like this:

```
var shuffle = function(arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

That might be a partial answer to what you're looking for, but it's really not clear to me what you're after overall.